# parse multiple xml file from multiple folder, having same format and store specific node's text in a variable

Tags: xml, python-2.7, pandas, xml-parsing

I have code for parsing multiple XML files from different directories:

```
for file in glob.iglob(os.path.join(dir, '100/**/*.xml')):
    with open(file) as f:
        data = etree.parse(f)
```

Format of XML files are:

```
<us1>
<us2>
<p-r>
<document-id>
<country>US</country>
<doc-number>07640598</doc-number>
<kind>B1</kind>
<date>20100105</date>
</document-id>
</p-r>
<ab>
<c>
<document-id>
<country>US1</country>
<doc-number>07640598989834</doc-number>
<kind>B5</kind>
<date>20100106</date>
</document-id>
</c>
</ab>
</us2></us1>
```

Now, i want to extract text in "doc-number" in between  from all the xml files present in the directory and store in a variable..i.e extracted data is  07640598.
How do i extract selected values and store it in a variable??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple XPath expression to get element of specific name in `ElementTree`, for example :

```
doc_no = data.find('.//doc-number')
if doc_no is not None:
    print doc_no.text
```

Slight change in the XPath expression if you meant to get `doc-number` that is child of `p-r` :

```
doc_no = data.find('.//p-r/doc-number')
```

Comment: ya, this is one way. But, what is I want to get "doc_no" from "p-r" tag and not from other tags??

Comment: @curiouscoder No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer ([more info about *accepting answer*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work))